# CSS converted from SASS not working

Tags: sass

Am trying to use SASS in my project. I wrote a SCSS and then converted that to CSS.

The SCSS I created is ,

```
$primaryColor: #D92231;

body {
  $primaryColor: #ccc;
  background: $primaryColor;
}

p {
  background-color: $primaryColor;
}

ui-btn {
    background-color: $primary-color;
}
```

Converted that SCSS to CSS by the command,

```
sass-convert style.css style.scss
```

Finally I got the CSS generated. Generated CSS is ,

```
$primaryColor: #D92231

body
  background: $primaryColor

p
  color: $primaryColor

ui-btn
  background-color: $primary-color
```

I linked this to my html page but no effect. Where am I going wrong ???

Comment: background: $primaryColor; should render out to background: #D92231 once it has been parsed, which means if you aren't getting those results when you have finished, something is wrong in-between.

Comment: Wow, it's almost like you didn't bother reading the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated CSS isn't actually CSS as `sass-convert` doesn't actually convert sass to css.

It converts CSS to SASS or SCSS dependant on what you want.

To convert the SCSS to SASS you will need to run the below script. You will need SASS installed.

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

Alternatively, you can run a script to have Ruby watch the SCSS file and update on every save.

Like so:

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Read more here: [Documentation](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass)

Comment: Tried with the above command. It generated the css but results the same. No effect.

Answer (score -2):

Try your Sass at sassmeister.com and you'll see that primary-color variable is not defined. I believe your code never gets compiled because of that error. See : [Sassmeister output in Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kubarium/80d29b575f1ade705f5a)

Comment: Could the person who downvoted my answer share his/her motivation?

Comment: It's true that `$primary-color` isn't defined in OP's example but your answer doesn't answer the question as to why `sass-convert` doesn't compile SCSS to CSS, which is properly explained in Stewartside's answer.